# Timed Android Eclipse Activity page

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

Could someone tell me how I could make an activity page for my android app appear for say 5 seconds then start a new activity. 
It's going to be my "Start up" page for the app so I'd only like it to show when the app begins.

Comment: use `Handler.post` with 5000 sec delay to start main screen from splash screen. u have any issue using handler?

Comment: Please *don't* do this. There's nothing more obnoxious than an artificial delay in your app's load time. If you have loading to do, then display it for that long, but 5 seconds for no reason? I'd immediately uninstall your app.

Comment: @kcoppock well maybe I'd just uninstall your app too :P

Comment: You can add splach screen & set a time for that splash screen so that after splash screen your activity will be started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This start activity called splash, you could find more about it here:

http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/android-simple-splash-screen.html
http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/12/android-splash-screen-tutorial.html

just google 'android splash screen'

Comment: Great thanks, sorry I'm a beginner so this is exactly what I'm after!

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity
{
    // Set the display time, in milliseconds (or extract it out as a configurable parameter)
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 500;
    Intent mainIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    //Finish the splash activity so it can't be returned to.
                    SplashActivity.this.finish();
                    // Create an Intent that will start the main activity.

                        mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MyChecklistsActivity.class);
                    SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

    }
}
```

or just google for "android splash activity", there are a lot of solutions